# Make background image auto slide

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that i am trying out from a template i got from codrops. I have been trying to make the background images auto rotate but i have failed. Can someone help me please: This is what i have

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Thumbnails Navigation Gallery with jQuery</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
        content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="Thumbnails Navigation Gallery with jQuery and CSS3"
        />
        <meta name="keywords" content="jquery, thumbnails, gallery, menu, navigation, full page, background, image, photo, portfolio, photography"
        />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"
        />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/Quicksand_Book_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Cufon.replace('span,p,h1', {
                textShadow: '0px 0px 1px #ffffff'
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            span.reference {
                font-family:Arial;
                position:fixed;
                left:10px;
                bottom:10px;
                font-size:11px;
            }
            span.reference a {
                color:#aaa;
                text-decoration:none;
                margin-right:20px;
            }
            span.reference a:hover {
                color:#ddd;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="st_main" class="st_main">
            <img src="images/album/1.jpg" alt="" class="st_preview" style="display:none;"
            />
            <div class="st_overlay"></div>
                <h1>Mark Sebastian</h1>

            <div id="st_loading" class="st_loading"><span>Loading...</span> 
            </div>
            <ul id="st_nav" class="st_navigation">
                <li class="album">  <span class="st_link">Newest Collection<span class="st_arrow_down"></span></span>
                    <div
                    class="st_wrapper st_thumbs_wrapper">
                        <div class="st_thumbs">
                            <img src="images/album/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album/1.jpg" />
                            <img src="images/album/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album/2.jpg" />
                            <img src="images/album/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album/3.jpg" />
                            <img src="images/album/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="images/album/4.jpg" />
                            <img src="images/album/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album/1.jpg" />
                            <img src="images/album/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album/2.jpg" />
                            <img src="images/album/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album/3.jpg" />
                            <img src="images/album/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="images/album/4.jpg" />
                            <img src="images/album/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album/1.jpg" />
                            <img src="images/album/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album/2.jpg" />
                            <img src="images/album/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album/3.jpg" />
                            <img src="images/album/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="images/album/4.jpg" />
                        </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="album">  <span class="st_link">Random Photography<span class="st_arrow_down"></span></span>
            <div
            class="st_wrapper st_thumbs_wrapper">
                <div class="st_thumbs">
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album/1.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album/2.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album/3.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="images/album/4.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album/1.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album/2.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album/3.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="images/album/4.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album/1.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album/2.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album/3.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="images/album/4.jpg" />
                </div>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="album">  <span class="st_link">Best Shots<span class="st_arrow_down"></span></span>
            <div
            class="st_wrapper st_thumbs_wrapper">
                <div class="st_thumbs">
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album/1.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album/2.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album/3.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="images/album/4.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album/1.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album/2.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album/3.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="images/album/4.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album/1.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album/2.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album/3.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="images/album/4.jpg" />
                </div>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li class="album">  <span class="st_link">Award Winning Collection<span  class="st_arrow_down"></span></span>
            <div
            class="st_wrapper st_thumbs_wrapper">
                <div class="st_thumbs">
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album/1.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album/2.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album/3.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="images/album/4.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album/1.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album/2.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album/3.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="images/album/4.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album/1.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="images/album/2.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="images/album/3.jpg" />
                    <img src="images/album/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="images/album/4.jpg" />
                </div>
                </div>
        </li>
        <li>    <span class="st_link">About<span class="st_arrow_down"></span></span>
            <div
            class="st_about st_thumbs_wrapper">
                <div class="st_subcontent">
                    <p>I am alone, and feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was created
                        for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed
                        in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence, that I neglect my talents.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div> <span class="reference">
                <a href="http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/28/thumbnails-navigation- gallery/">back to the Codrops tutorial</a>
                <a  href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/markjsebastian/">Photos by Mark Sebastian</a>
            </span>

        </div>
        <!-- The JavaScript -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                //the loading image
                var $loader = $('#st_loading');
                //the ul element 
                var $list = $('#st_nav');
                //the current image being shown
                var $currImage = $('#st_main').children('img:first');

                //let's load the current image 
                //and just then display the navigation menu
                $('<img>').load(function () {
                    $loader.hide();
                    $currImage.fadeIn(3000);
                    //slide out the menu
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $list.animate({
                            'left': '0px'
                        }, 500);
                    },
                    1000);
                }).attr('src', $currImage.attr('src'));

                //calculates the width of the div element 
                //where the thumbs are going to be displayed
                buildThumbs();

                function buildThumbs() {
                    $list.children('li.album').each(function () {
                        var $elem = $(this);
                        var $thumbs_wrapper = $elem.find('.st_thumbs_wrapper');
                        var $thumbs = $thumbs_wrapper.children(':first');
                        //each thumb has 180px and we add 3 of   margin
                        var finalW = $thumbs.find('img').length * 183;
                        $thumbs.css('width', finalW + 'px');
                        //make this element scrollable
                        makeScrollable($thumbs_wrapper, $thumbs);
                    });
                }

                //clicking on the menu items (up and down arrow)
                //makes the thumbs div appear, and hides the current 
                //opened menu (if any)
                $list.find('.st_arrow_down').live('click', function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    hideThumbs();
                    $this.addClass('st_arrow_up').removeClass('st_arrow_down');
                    var $elem = $this.closest('li');
                    $elem.addClass('current').animate({
                        'height': '170px'
                    }, 200);
                    var $thumbs_wrapper = $this.parent().next();
                    $thumbs_wrapper.show(200);
                });
                $list.find('.st_arrow_up').live('click', function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.addClass('st_arrow_down').removeClass('st_arrow_up');
                    hideThumbs();
                });

                //clicking on a thumb, replaces the large image
                $list.find('.st_thumbs img').bind('click', function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $loader.show();
                    $('<img class="st_preview"/>').load(function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var $currImage = $('#st_main').children('img:first');
                        $this.insertBefore($currImage);
                        $loader.hide();
                        $currImage.fadeOut(2000, function () {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    }).attr('src', $this.attr('alt'));
                }).bind('mouseenter', function () {
                    $(this).stop().animate({
                        'opacity': '1'
                    });
                }).bind('mouseleave', function () {
                    $(this).stop().animate({
                        'opacity': '0.7'
                    });
                });

                //function to hide the current opened menu
                function hideThumbs() {
                    $list.find('li.current')
                        .animate({
                        'height': '50px'
                    }, 400, function () {
                        $(this).removeClass('current');
                    })
                        .find('.st_thumbs_wrapper')
                        .hide(200)
                        .andSelf()
                        .find('.st_link span')
                        .addClass('st_arrow_down')
                        .removeClass('st_arrow_up');
                }

                //makes the thumbs div scrollable
                //on mouse move the div scrolls automatically
                function makeScrollable($outer, $inner) {
                    var extra = 800;
                    //Get menu width
                    var divWidth = $outer.width();
                    //Remove scrollbars
                    $outer.css({
                        overflow: 'hidden'
                    });
                    //Find last image in container
                    var lastElem = $inner.find('img:last');
                    $outer.scrollLeft(0);
                    //When user move mouse over menu
                    $outer.unbind('mousemove').bind('mousemove', function (e) {
                        var containerWidth = lastElem[0].offsetLeft + lastElem.outerWidth() + 2 * extra;
                        var left = (e.pageX - $outer.offset().left) * (containerWidth - divWidth) / divWidth - extra;
                        $outer.scrollLeft(left);
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

The background image appears immediately after the first div. its the one with

```
<img src="images/album/1.jpg" alt="" class="st_preview" style="display:none;"
/>
```

Can someone just help me on how i can auto rotate it with another image. Have a look at my javascript and let me know what i can change

Comment: Do you mean rotate, like on an axis or like a slideshow? I'm assuming you mean the latter, in which case I'd use something like this http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: yes i meant like a slideshow

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a very flexible background image rotating solution

[http://www.marcofolio.net](http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/advanced_jquery_background_image_slideshow.html)

[How to rotate and fade background images in and out with javascript/ASP.NET/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146153/how-to-rotate-and-fade-background-images-in-and-out-with-javascript-asp-net-css)